# HTML5 Image Upload, Crop and Save

Tags: javascript, html

I just followed the tutorial from here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/, which was referenced in another stackoverflow post and which was recommended for beginners.

I have built the code so far and tested it in my test.php, but it doesn't seem to work (for me). After I upload a picture simply nothing happens. I already went over the code on the website again and again, but my knowledge limits my ability to find the error.

My test.php:

```
...
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" multiple>
</form>

<script>
// from an input element
var filesToUpload = input.file;

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var MAX_WIDTH = 200;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 260;
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;

if (width > height) {
if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
width = MAX_WIDTH;
}
} else {
if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
height = MAX_HEIGHT;
}
}
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

var imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
var data = imgData.data;
var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
for (var i = 0, ii = pixels.data.length; i < ii; i += 4) {
var r = pixels.data[i + 0];
var g =pixels.data[i + 1];
var b = this.pixels.data[i + 2];
data[i + 0] = (r * .393) + (g *.769) + (b * .189);
data[i + 1] = (r * .349) + (g *.686) + (b * .168)
data[i + 2] = (r * .272) + (g *.534) + (b * .131)
data[i + 3] = 255;
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

</script>

...
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: `var filesToUpload = input.files;` the variable input does not exist

Comment: var filesToUpload = input.file;  try this..

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/live-image-upload-jquery-php-mysql/ ..try this

Comment: **First** : you need to wait for your image has loaded before being able to draw it on the canvas, and moreover to grab its content. **Second**:  the method you want is `ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height)` not `ctx.createImageData()` which will only return an empty imageData all filled with `0`, so your filter will be a little bit useless, except if the intended goal is to create an opaque black image. And remember to call this getImageData only after the image has loaded and been drawn on the canvas, so your `toDataURL` should be passed to an callback function, since all this will be async

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies and help, but it didn't solve the problem. I tried `var filesToUpload = input.file;`. @Kaiidoo I also tried to replace `ctx.createImageData()` with `ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height)`, but nothing is showing up. I would actually be happy to even see a black box, just anything that shows me the code is working at any point.

Comment: No one having an idea of how to get this to work? or is the code just wrong in general? im no JS expert to identify it without help :(